# Pop UP registration form

Tags: magento-1.9, register

I used this tutorial http://www.demacmedia.com/magento-commerce/mini-tutorial-magento-newsletter-pop-up-with-cookie/

to create a cookie based popup that has the newsletter form, how can i place the magento registration form instead.

Comment: have you applied below solution ?

Comment: Yes Anil I have and they both work. But heres what I am trying to do have a multi step popup form step 1 = enter email and register which i have working but its a frankenstein then either click submit or continue to next step step 2 = choose your vehicle those custom attribute for customer exstension in all practice i would much rather it use amasty parts finder exstension (year make model engine) thats another project though so for now the custom custom attributes extension to keep it simple. at which point the user can click submit  or next step 3= first name last name and phone. then submit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this lines of `newsletterpopup.xml`

```
<reference name="before_body_end">
    <block type="core/template" name="newsletter_popup" as="newsletter_popup" template="val/newsletter-popup.phtml" />
</reference>
```

TO :

```
<reference name="before_body_end">
    <block type="customer/form_register" name="newsletter_popup" as="newsletter_popup" template="val/newsletter-popup.phtml" />
</reference>
```

Now replace `newsletter-popup.phtml` file with this content

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery(document).ready(function() {

        var check_cookie = "<?php echo Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->get('popup-shown'); ?>";

        if(!check_cookie) {
            beginNewsletterForm();
            <?php Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->set('popup-shown', 'true', 5);?>
        }
    });

    function beginNewsletterForm () {
        jQuery.fancybox({
            'width': '910',
            'height': '450',
            'padding': '0px',
            'autoDimensions': false,
            'autoScale': false,
            'autoSize': false,
            'transitionIn': 'fade',
            'transitionOut': 'fade',
            'showCloseButton': true,
            'type': 'inline',
            'href': '#newsletter-popup'
        });
        jQuery("#newsletter-popup").trigger('click');
    }
</script>

<div style="display:none;">
    <div id="newsletter-popup" class="container">
        <div class="account-create">
            <div class="page-title">
                <h1><?php echo $this->__('Create an Account') ?></h1>
            </div>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('form_fields_before')?>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('customer.form.register.extra')?>
            <form action="<?php echo $this->getPostActionUrl() ?>" method="post" id="form-validate">
                <div class="fieldset">
                    <input type="hidden" name="success_url" value="<?php echo $this->getSuccessUrl() ?>" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="error_url" value="<?php echo $this->getErrorUrl() ?>" />
                    <h2 class="legend"><?php echo $this->__('Personal Information') ?></h2>
                    <ul class="form-list">
                        <li class="fields">
                            <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('customer/widget_name')->setObject($this->getFormData())->setForceUseCustomerAttributes(true)->toHtml() ?>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <label for="email_address" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Email Address') ?></label>
                            <div class="input-box">
                                <input type="text" name="email" id="email_address" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getFormData()->getEmail()) ?>" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Email Address')) ?>" class="input-text validate-email required-entry" />
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <?php if ($this->isNewsletterEnabled()): ?>
                        <li class="control">
                            <div class="input-box">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="is_subscribed" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Sign Up for Newsletter')) ?>" value="1" id="is_subscribed"<?php if($this->getFormData()->getIsSubscribed()): ?> checked="checked"<?php endif; ?> class="checkbox" />
                            </div>
                            <label for="is_subscribed"><?php echo $this->__('Sign Up for Newsletter') ?></label>
                            <?php /* Extensions placeholder */ ?>
                            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('customer.form.register.newsletter')?>
                        </li>
                        <?php endif ?>
                    <?php $_dob = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('customer/widget_dob') ?>
                    <?php if ($_dob->isEnabled()): ?>
                        <li><?php echo $_dob->setDate($this->getFormData()->getDob())->toHtml() ?></li>
                    <?php endif ?>
                    <?php $_taxvat = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('customer/widget_taxvat') ?>
                    <?php if ($_taxvat->isEnabled()): ?>
                        <li><?php echo $_taxvat->setTaxvat($this->getFormData()->getTaxvat())->toHtml() ?></li>
                    <?php endif ?>
                    <?php $_gender = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('customer/widget_gender') ?>
                    <?php if ($_gender->isEnabled()): ?>
                        <li><?php echo $_gender->setGender($this->getFormData()->getGender())->toHtml() ?></li>
                    <?php endif ?>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            <?php if($this->getShowAddressFields()): ?>
                <div class="fieldset">
                    <input type="hidden" name="create_address" value="1" />
                    <h2 class="legend"><?php echo $this->__('Address Information') ?></h2>
                    <ul class="form-list">
                        <li class="fields">
                            <div class="field">
                                <label for="company"><?php echo $this->__('Company') ?></label>
                                <div class="input-box">
                                    <input type="text" name="company" id="company" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getFormData()->getCompany()) ?>" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Company')) ?>" class="input-text <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('company') ?>" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="field">
                                <label for="telephone" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Telephone') ?></label>
                                <div class="input-box">
                                    <input type="text" name="telephone" id="telephone" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getFormData()->getTelephone()) ?>" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Telephone')) ?>" class="input-text <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('telephone') ?>" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    <?php $_streetValidationClass = $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('street'); ?>
                        <li class="wide">
                            <label for="street_1" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Street Address') ?></label>
                            <div class="input-box">
                                <input type="text" name="street[]" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getFormData()->getStreet(1)) ?>" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Street Address')) ?>" id="street_1" class="input-text <?php echo $_streetValidationClass ?>" />
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    <?php $_streetValidationClass = trim(str_replace('required-entry', '', $_streetValidationClass)); ?>
                    <?php for ($_i = 2, $_n = $this->helper('customer/address')->getStreetLines(); $_i <= $_n; $_i++): ?>
                        <li class="wide">
                            <div class="input-box">
                                <input type="text" name="street[]" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getFormData()->getStreet($_i)) ?>" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Street Address %s', $_i)) ?>" id="street_<?php echo $_i ?>" class="input-text <?php echo $_streetValidationClass ?>" />
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    <?php endfor; ?>
                        <li class="fields">
                            <div class="field">
                                <label for="city" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('City') ?></label>
                                <div class="input-box">
                                    <input type="text" name="city" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getFormData()->getCity()) ?>" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('City')) ?>" class="input-text <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('city') ?>" id="city" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="field">
                                <label for="region_id" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('State/Province') ?></label>
                                <div class="input-box">
                                    <select id="region_id" name="region_id" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('State/Province')) ?>" class="validate-select" style="display:none;">
                                        <option value=""><?php echo $this->__('Please select region, state or province') ?></option>
                                    </select>
                                    <script type="text/javascript">
                                    //<![CDATA[
                                        $('region_id').setAttribute('defaultValue', "<?php echo $this->getFormData()->getRegionId() ?>");
                                    //]]>
                                    </script>
                                    <input type="text" id="region" name="region" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getRegion()) ?>" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('State/Province')) ?>" class="input-text <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('region') ?>" style="display:none;" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="fields">
                            <div class="field">
                                <label for="zip" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Zip/Postal Code') ?></label>
                                <div class="input-box">
                                    <input type="text" name="postcode" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getFormData()->getPostcode()) ?>" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Zip/Postal Code')) ?>" id="zip" class="input-text validate-zip-international <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('postcode') ?>" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="field">
                                <label for="country" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Country') ?></label>
                                <div class="input-box">
                                    <?php echo $this->getCountryHtmlSelect() ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <input type="hidden" name="default_billing" value="1" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="default_shipping" value="1" />
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
                <div class="fieldset">
                    <h2 class="legend"><?php echo $this->__('Login Information') ?></h2>
                    <ul class="form-list">
                        <li class="fields">
                            <div class="field">
                                <label for="password" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Password') ?></label>
                                <div class="input-box">
                                    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Password')) ?>" class="input-text required-entry validate-password" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="field">
                                <label for="confirmation" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Confirm Password') ?></label>
                                <div class="input-box">
                                    <input type="password" name="confirmation" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Confirm Password')) ?>" id="confirmation" class="input-text required-entry validate-cpassword" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('form.additional.info'); ?>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="buttons-set">
                    <p class="required"><?php echo $this->__('* Required Fields') ?></p>
                    <button type="submit" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Submit')) ?>" class="button"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Submit') ?></span></span></button>
                </div>
            </form>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            //<![CDATA[
                var dataForm = new VarienForm('form-validate', true);
                <?php if($this->getShowAddressFields()): ?>
                new RegionUpdater('country', 'region', 'region_id', <?php echo $this->helper('directory')->getRegionJson() ?>, undefined, 'zip');
                <?php endif; ?>
            //]]>
            </script>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE (for Amar_Profile extension):**

Change XML With:

```
<reference name="before_body_end">
    <block type="profile/customer_account_create" name="newsletter_popup" as="newsletter_popup" template="val/newsletter-popup.phtml" before="captcha" after="-"/>
</reference>
```

Change `newsletter-popup.phtml` file with:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery(document).ready(function() {

        var check_cookie = "<?php echo Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->get('popup-shown'); ?>";

        if(!check_cookie) {
            beginNewsletterForm();
            <?php Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->set('popup-shown', 'true', 5);?>
        }
    });

    function beginNewsletterForm () {
        jQuery.fancybox({
            'width': '910',
            'height': '450',
            'padding': '0px',
            'autoDimensions': false,
            'autoScale': false,
            'autoSize': false,
            'transitionIn': 'fade',
            'transitionOut': 'fade',
            'showCloseButton': true,
            'type': 'inline',
            'href': '#newsletter-popup'
        });
        jQuery("#newsletter-popup").trigger('click');
    }
</script>
<div style="display:none;">
    <div id="newsletter-popup" class="container">
    <?php
    foreach ($this->getAttributeCodes() as $_attributeCode) {
        ?>
        <li class="fields amar-profile">
        <?php echo $this->getAttributeFrontendHtmlControl($_attributeCode); ?>
        </li>
            <?php
        }
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.observe("dom:loaded",function(){
        var amarProfileLis = $$('li.amar-profile'); 

        amarProfileLis.each(function(el,ind){
            var liElement = new Element("li");
            liElement.addClassName("fields");
            liElement.innerHTML = el.innerHTML;

            if($$("li.control").length > 0)
            {
                $$("li.control").each(function(e,i){
                    if((e.down("input",0).readAttribute("id") == 'is_subscribed') && (i == 0))
                    {
                        e.insert({"before":liElement});
                    }
                });
            }
            else
            {
                ulElement.insert({"bottom":liElement});
            }
            el.remove();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for replying and that almost gets me there, however I am using a exstension for extra customer attributes and those do not display on the popup form like they do on the website registration form, where should I fetch my registration form code from so I can replicate those additional customer attributes

Comment: that exstension name is Amar_Profile the website is http://freedom-performance.com Thanks for your help

Comment: check Updated answer

Comment: Thanks Anil that showed the custom profile field but it didnt show the registration form :) I need the entire registration form plus the amar custom fields basically i want them to be able to register via the pop up and need both the registration form and the extended fields. I tried simply merging the two code sets but that didnt work, as i dont know what I am doing i guess, learning though. Thanks for your help really saving the day.